# I can't install pyPDF package No distributions at all found for pyPdf

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, pypdf

I try install this package...

```
$ pip search pyPdf     
PyPDFLite                 - Simple PDF Writer.
pypdfocr                  - Converts a scanned PDF into an OCR'ed pdf using Tesseract-OCR and Ghostscript
pyPdf                     - PDF toolkit
PyPDF2                    - PDF toolkit
pyjon.reports             - Pyjon.Reports is a module bridging z3c.rml, genshi and pypdf together to provide a simple mean of creating templated pdf documents in python.
pypdf2xml                 - A reimplementation of pdftoxml in Python, using pdfMiner. Handles unicode characters better.
pypdflib                  - Pango Cairo based Python PDF Library
pypdf2table               - PDF table extraction tool
```

And i run install the package

```
$ pip install pyPdf                 
Downloading/unpacking pyPdf
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyPdf
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pyPdf to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pyPdf
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpgEc3B
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Specipy [`--allow-external`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#allow-external), [`--allow-unverified`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#cmdoption--allow-unverified) options:

```
pip install --allow-external pyPdf --allow-unverified pyPdf pyPdf
```

Specifying `--allow-unverified` implies `--allow-external`; can be omitted.

```
pip install --allow-unverified pyPdf pyPdf
```

Comment: I run the command that you answered. But I have this error. `ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='stompstompstomp.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /pyPdf/ (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)'`
I am thinking change the package that has a dependencies with PyPdf. Like in my project xhtml2pdf or django-xhtml2pdf.

Do you can suggest other package that does this functionality?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @LucasSimon, `pip install --allow-unverified ..` works for me. See [a screencast I just recorded](https://asciinema.org/a/7845)

Answer (score 2):

pyPdf is no longer updated, you can check it on their site [here](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)

So you'd better use other package like pyPdf2. If you insist to use pyPdf, you can try the method falsetru posted

Answer (score 0):

If you use Debian/Ubuntu, you can use standard repository to install the corresponding package:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install python-pypdf
```